# Export from piped while loop in Bash?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to modify some exports. I understand that this code doesn't work because its body executes in a subshell, but how do I fix it?

```
export | sed 's/gcc.4.2/gcc64/g' | while read line; do $line; done
```

Comment: Do you want to change the export  and then set the environment variable again? If yes then you have to redirect the output to another file and then source the file

Comment: @Raghuram: Yeah... is there no way to do this from within BASH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is probably the better solution:

```
export | sed 's/gcc.4.2/gcc64/g' > ~/tmp/file
. ~/tmp/file
```

but in case you want to avoid the creation of a temp file

```
eval $( export | sed 's/gcc.4.2/gcc64/; s/$/;/' )
```

should do the trick.

Comment: This will work with other shells such as Bourne and Korn (give or take the `~` for the Bourne shell).  It is probably sub-optimal for `bash` given the various extra tricks it has up its sleeve, notably process substitution.

Answer (score 5):

By arranging for the current shell to read the commands with 'process substitution':

```
. <(export | sed 's/gcc.4.2/gcc64/g')
```

Or:

```
source <(export | sed 's/gcc.4.2/gcc64/g')
```

(which is more visible, though not as succinct, as the `.` command).

Comment: +1 although `sed -n 's/gcc.4.2/gcc64/gp'` would be more efficient.

Comment: Only setting that which needs to be set - yes, it would be more efficient.  It isn't quite the same as the original, but it is in line with the intent of the original.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without the need for a temp file and I ***highly*** discourage the use of `eval` as you open up your system to all kinds of security problems with it.

```
while read -r line; do $(sed -n 's/gcc.4.2/gcc64/gp' <<<"$line"); done < <(export)
```

Also, by using `sed -n`, this only exports those entries that sed changed.